# Customize RatingBar stars differently

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ratingbar

I am trying to customize each star of a `RatingBar` to look differently.

As I look at its source code [RatingBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/RatingBar.java) or its super classes [AbsSeekBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java) / [ProgressBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java), I was unable to identify such option, it can only provide a progress / secondaryProgress and background for the entire View. The closest thing would be using thumbDrawable, but its utility is totally different (for indeterminate `SeekBar`).

Is there any option besides doing a totally custom View to replicate such functionality?

Here is a picture with a RatingBar I am trying to create: 
[image: custom ratingBar]

I have to mention that each star (last selected star), would have a different "face", and there would always be exactly 5 stars (`numStars` property). Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this library [starBar by badoo](https://github.com/badoo/StarBar.git) having one to ten stars with different color images like red orange yellow green u can change the images in resource to get your choice of bar.
Also this [link](http://www.geeks.gallery/how-to-code-custom-ratingbar-in-android/) would be helpful.

Comment: Although I am inclined not to use a Custom View which creates a similar functionality to RatingBar, but extending View class, I think that you deserve the bounty offered for this question, because your answer is close enough to replicate what I asked. I will leave the question open for some more time, after which I shall accept your answer.